# React Component with SubComponent - hot reload does not work

Tags: reactjs, components, hot-reload, subcomponent

I have an issue with my project with a simple `SubComponent`. If I do any changes inside that `SubComonent` it is not hot reloaded. I am not sure how to fix it.

I have components defined like this:

```
// Component.tsx
export const Component = () => {
  return <div>Component</div>;
};

Component.SubComponent = function SubComponent() {
  return <div>Hello From Sub</div>;
};

export const SubComponent1 = function SubComponent1() {
  return <div>Hello From Sub1</div>;
};
```

And usage:

```
// App.tsx
<Component.SubComponent />
<SubComponent1 />
```

If I do changes in `Component.SubComponent` it is not reloaded, but if I do changes in `SubComponent1` it works well.

I have tested this with the clean create-react-app install and it does not work there too.

Any ideas on how to fix this or what is wrong with the code? I found quite a lot of articles about sub components on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The approach seems bad to me.

```
export const Component = () => {
  return <div>Component</div>;
};

Component.SubComponent = function SubComponent() {
  return <div>Hello From Sub</div>;
};
```

Export components one by one.

```
export const Form = () => (<></>)
export const Item = () => (<></>)

import * as Form from '...'

<Form.Form>
  <Form.Item>
  </Form.Item>
</Form.Form>
```

I see that `<Form.Form />` is ugly. Another way would be:

```
export const Form = () => (<></>)
export const Item = () => (<></>)

import { Form, Item as FormItem } from '...'

<Form>
  <Form.Item>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```